# How to plot only some cells with certain values of an array and others not with matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have an image that consists of float values and another one that consist only of ones and zeros. I want to plot the second image over the first one, but I only want to plot the ones from the second image. The zeros shall not be plotted.

Ì have tried the following code and I also changed the alpha of y to 1. The problem is, that either the red windows of y are changed from x (alpha of y = 0.5), or one can not even see the plots of x (alpha of y=1).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random(size=(20,20))
y = np.random.randint(2, size=(20,20))

fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(x, cmap="Greys", alpha = 0.5)
plt.imshow(y, cmap="Reds", alpha = 0.5)
plt.show()
```

How can I only plot the ones of y?

UPDATE:
Thank you for your answers! But this is not want I am looking for. I will explain again:

The result should be something like: x as background and every position, where y is 1, should be colored pure red.

Comment: your question is more about filtering/masking arrays than plotting, right?

Comment: Inprinciple the answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991649/matplotlib-imshow-how-to-apply-a-mask-on-the-matrix). Alternatively, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578752/how-can-i-plot-nan-values-as-a-special-color-with-imshow-in-matplotlib) would be a way, to do it, setting the bad value to a color with alpha=0, like (0,0,0,0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the approach in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991649/matplotlib-imshow-how-to-apply-a-mask-on-the-matrix) answer linked by @ImportanceOfBeingEarnest, the exact solution in your case would look like below. Here, `np.ma.masked_where` will mask your `y` array at places where it is 0. The resulting array will only contain 1.

EDIT: The problem of overlaying seems to stem from the choice of `cmap`. If you don't specify the `cmap` for the `y`, you can clearly see below that indeed only 1's are plotted and overlaid on the top of `x`. In order to have a discrete color (red in your case), you can create a custom color map

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import colors

x = np.random.random(size=(20,20))
y = np.random.randint(2, size=(20,20))

y_new =np.ma.masked_where(y==0, y)
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(['red'])

fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(x, cmap="Greys", alpha = 0.5)
plt.imshow(y_new, cmap=cmap, alpha=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but please see my update. This solution still mixes the two plots somehow... They should look like y is layed over x, but only the ones in y are plotted.

Answer (score 0):

We can inverse *"The result should be [..] x as background and every position, where y is 1, should be colored pure red."*, namely to just plot `x`, masked by `y` and set the background to red.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.random.randint(2, size=(20,20))
x = np.random.random(size=(20,20))
X = np.ma.array(x, mask=y)

fig = plt.figure()

plt.imshow(X, cmap="Greys")
plt.gca().set_facecolor("red")
plt.show()
```

[image]

There are of course related Q&As like

[Matplotlib imshow: how to apply a mask on the matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32991649/matplotlib-imshow-how-to-apply-a-mask-on-the-matrix) or 
[How can I plot NaN values as a special color with imshow in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578752/how-can-i-plot-nan-values-as-a-special-color-with-imshow-in-matplotlib)

and there is also an example on the matplotlib page: [Image masked](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_masked.html)